# How do i get busybox to start the system with specified device instead of the default vgubuntu-root?

Tags: boot, initramfs, busybox

My system drops me into busybox/initramfs terminal and tells me /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root doesn't exist. But what does exist in `/dev/mapper` is nvme0n1p3_crypt so i probably need to use that instead of vgubuntu-root. I also tried to get cryptsetup to make that file via `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 vgubuntu-root` but cryptsetup tells me that the device is already in use. I also tried to edit /cryptroot/crypttab but there doesn't seem to be any editor in that environment. As you can see by the use of cryptsetup the disk is encrypted.

Comment: I also just tried to `cryptsetup luksClose nvme0n1p3_crypt` and then `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 vgubuntu-root` and then exit. Which first said that mounting /dev on /root/dev failed because no such file or directory and the same with /run and vgubuntu-root to /root also failed with no such device and "Free initramfs and switch to another root fs: chroot to NEW_ROOT, delete all in /, move NEW_ROOT to /. execute NEW_INIT. PID must be 1 NEW_ROOT must be a mount point.

Comment: I just ran exit again which simply resulted in a kernel panic